# How to delete duplicated numeric vector elements based on name attribute?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a numeric vector defined like this:

```
c(A = 1, B = 2, A = 3, C = 4, D = 4)
```

which gives result of:

```
A B A C D 
1 2 3 4 4
```

Now, I want to remove the duplicate elements, but not based on the values, but instead based on the name attributes. I have two elements with the same name A. So I want to keep just one of them (which one is kept is not important in my case), and remove the rest from the vector. So, after removing the duplicates, I want my final vector to looks like this:

```
A B C D 
1 2 4 4
```

I know there is the `unique()` function, but it seems to remove the duplicates based on the value. Is there any way to remove based on the name attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `duplicated` function and negation on the names of the vector to remove the elements with duplicate names:

```
x <- c(A = 1, B = 2, A = 3, C = 4, D = 4)
x[!duplicated(names(x))]
```

gives:

```
A B C D 
1 2 4 4
```

Another option as suggested by @lmo in the comments:

```
x[unique(names(x))]
```

which will give the same result.

Comment: @lmo nice! Added it to my answer, but if you want to post it as your own solution, I will delete the addition.

Comment: Thanks to both. Good answers.